# Angular Material: How can I set the width of spans to be the same without setting a fixed width or using Javascript?

Tags: angular-material

I have 3 containers which contain an input and a span. The span width can change dynamically because I will be adding localization so I don't know the max width of the text. Therefore, is there a way that I can set all spans to be the same width without setting a fixed width or using Javascript? Preferably using Angular Material.

See example here: http://codepen.io/cmacdonnacha/pen/PzWWda

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div layout="column">
    <md-input-container md-no-float layout="row">
      <span>From:</span>
      <input type="email">
    </md-input-container>

    <md-input-container md-no-float layout="row">
      <span>To:</span>
      <input type="email">
    </md-input-container>

    <md-input-container md-no-float layout="row">
      <span>Cc:</span>
      <input type="email">
    </md-input-container>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `div` element for each `md-input-container` and use `span` with `flex` attribute. Here is the code for that.

```
<div layout="column">
<div layout="row" flex layout-align="start center">
  <span flex="initial">From:</span>
  <md-input-container flex>
    <input type="from">
  </md-input-container>
</div>
<div layout="row" flex layout-align="start center">
  <span flex="initial">To:</span>
  <md-input-container flex>
    <input type="email">
  </md-input-container>
</div>
<div layout="row" flex layout-align="start center">
  <span flex="initial">Subject:</span>
  <md-input-container flex>
    <input type="subject">
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

You can define the value `flex` as desired to get the required result. Here is the working code. http://codepen.io/next1/pen/yJgKBR

Edit: As you will use `inital` as `flex` value, span element will only use the space required by it but you will lose the alignment in that way.

Comment: Thanks! It's not really the best solution though as it's pretty much the same as hardcoding the width of the span...the input just overlaps. See [codepen](http://codepen.io/cmacdonnacha/pen/jryzbp)

Comment: Yea i definitely want to keep the alignment as well. May not be possible without specifying a width I suppose.

Comment: Yes you are right. I wolud prefer using fixed `flex` value and perper alignment.

Comment: Yea. Thanks! I'll select this as the answer anyway :-)

Comment: Can you switch back to the version where you didn't have "initial" so that others will see the correct answer? Thanks :-)

Comment: I just updated the link. Giving exmple for both the cases with discussed.